# Why does this regex to remove empty <p></p> tags from a string fail?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen related answers, but that brought me to the following, which still does not work and I don't know why.

I have the following example:

```
var oldHTML = "<p></p><p></p><p>Fred was here.</p><p></p><p></p>;

var newHTML = oldHTML.replace(/<p><\/p>/g, "");

alert(newHTML);
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQrbb/

Check the console to see the error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

I am expecting to get the newHTML to be "Fred was here." wrapped in 'p' tags.

Ugh - regex is powerful but often a PITA. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"and I don't know why."* But the error tells why: You have a syntax error. Hence check your syntax (there are only three lines, it shouldn't be that difficult). Firefox provides a more useful error message: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`.

Comment: @Eric http://jsfiddle.net/BQrbb/2/

Comment: Where does your pattern appear?  Is it between `<script>...</script>` tags in an HTML page, or external?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/BQrbb/3/

Comment: My bad - I did miss the ending quote in the question and the JSFiddle. However, in my code I still get the error and the ending quote is there. This is driving me nuts. The regex works fine if I want to replace simple text, but the '/' of the </p> tag is messing things up. I added the backslash escape - but it causes the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a regex problem. Your string needs a closing quote mark.